# Unable to create a new iPython notebook in Python 2.7.11

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

```
Unexpected error while saving file: 
    Untitled.ipynb [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I get the error above while creating a new iPython notebook.

I am using anaconda. And I am starting jupyter notebook from anaconda only. What can be the problem?

I have the anaconda folder on my desktop in ubuntu.

Comment: you started ipython notebook in a folder in which you have no write permissions.

Comment: I am using anaconda. And I am starting jupyter notebook from anaconda only. What can be the problem?

Comment: I have the anaconda folder on my desktop in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

sudo chmod -R 777 /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

Answer (score 0):

Change the folder owner to the current user. For example, if your username is `yourname`:

```
sudo chown -R yourname:yourname ~/.local/share/jupyter
```